# Are "adult" and "adulterate" cognates?

Tags: meaning, etymology, latin, derivation

The word **[adult](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=adult&searchmode=none)** appear to have derived from the Latin term *adultus*, meaning *grown up, mature, adult, ripe*.

**[Adulterate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=adulterate&searchmode=none)** (and its cognate *[adultery](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=adultery&searchmode=none)*) is reported to derive from the Latin *adulterare* - *to falsify, corrupt*.

Are the meanings and derivation of **adult** and **adulterate**, directly related, or is this just a coincidence of spelling?

Comment: It's worth remembering that grown-ups are grouped by gender into adults and adultresses.

Comment: bib, as Robusto said, I think they are not strictly cognates because  'adulterate', more precisely, deives from the Latin 'ad alterum' (changing, transforming), while 'adult' has a different etimology, and +1 for this interesting question, though.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Latin, not English.

Comment: The answer seems to be yes, along with old according to [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old) - "Middle English, from Old English eald; akin to Old High German alt old, Latin alere to nourish, alescere to grow, altus high, deep".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are relevant discussions from three authorities.

From John Ayto, *Arcade Dictionary of Word Origins* (1990):

> **adultery** [14(th century)]  Neither *adultery* nor the related *adulterate* have any connection with *adult*. Both come ultimately from the Latin verb *adulterare* 'debauch, corrupt' (which may have been based on Latin *alter* 'other,' with the notion of pollution from some extraneous source). By the regular processes of phonetic change, *adulterare* passed into Old French as *avoutrer*, and this was the form which first reached English, as *avouter* (used both verbally, 'commit adultery,' and nominally, 'adulterer') and as the nouns *avoutery* 'adultery,' and *avouterer* 'adulterer.' Almost from the first they coexisted in English beside *adult-* forms deriving either from Low French or directly from Latin, and during the 15th to 17th centuries these gradually ousted the *avout-* forms. *Adulter*, the equivalent of *avouter*, clung on until the end of the 18th century, but the noun was superseded in the end by *adulterer* and the verb by a new form, *adulterate*, directly based on the past participle of Latin *adulterare*, which continued to mean 'commit adultery' until the mid 19th century.

From Robert Hendrickson, *The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins* (1997):

> **adultery.** Contrary to popular opinion this word is not related to *adult*. It can be traced back to the Latin *adulterare*, "to pollute, to commit adultery," which also gives us the word *adulterate*. Interestingly, the English word *adulterate* once meant to commit adultery, Shakespeare using it in *King John* (1596): "She adulterates hourly with thine Uncle John."

From Merriam-Webster, *Webster's Word Histories* (1989):

> **adolescent** The English adjectives *adolescent*, *adult*, and *old*, which designate stages of life, share a common Indo-European ancestor, whose meaning was 'to nourish' or 'to grow'. *Alere*, 'to nourish', and its derivative *alescere*, 'to grow', are Latin descendants of this Indo-European root. Latin *adolescere*, 'to grow up', is formed by the addition of the common Latin prefix *ad-*, meaning 'to' or 'at', to the verb *alescere*. The present participle of *adolescere* is *adolescens*, which gives us English *adolescent*; an *adolescent* person, then, is one who is growing up. A person who is an *adult* has grown up: Latin *adultus* is the past participle of *adolescere*.